# Why is my ISP IONOS when my site is hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-route53, ionos

Hoping someone can shed some light on a question I have...

My website is hosted on AWS Route 53, however when I scan my domain name on cyberscan and similar sites, it surfaces IP addresses hosted on IONOS.
We don't have an IONOS account so I don't know why they're showing as the ISP - is this a case that they are the local ISP and therefore my AWS site is hosted by them for particular regions?

I'm looking to change some settings for the IP addresses which are showing as hosted by IONOS, hence why I'm confused, because I cannot access them through AWS but also don't have an IONOS account.

Any help appreciated - let me know if any of this needs clarifying!

Comment: Without details, we can only guess. Note: your website is not hosted by Route 53 nor does Route 53 provide IP addresses. Where is your website hosted? What is the domain name? Without information, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a criticism, but an observation - you clearly don't understand how things are connected which is why you are getting confused. You can't host a website on Route53 as this is a DNS management service. On AWS you can host websites on services such as EC2, S3 and many more.

**Registrar**

aka. company you purchased the domain name from

example.com

Configured to use Nameservers ns1.your-registrar.com, or ns1.aws.com (these examples are made up, for the first example, find this in your registrar account, for the second example you create a Zone in AWS Route53 which generates you 4x Nameserver records that you then apply at your Registrar)

**How it all connects**

Registrar example.com --> DNS --> example.com --> IP 1.2.3.4 --> Web Hosting company --> Lots of super complex stuff --> index.html

Don't worry about not understanding right now, it's a complex topic and you're clearly at the early stages. Start by drawing the dots and understanding how they connect. It's complex, so take it a step at a time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed reply Michael - I had indeed been thrown a curveball while my colleague was on leave but this helped me get to the bottom of it!